# Joining Different Database Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in Access pulling from databases. There is no primary key linking the two tables, because the databases pull from different programs.

Using SQL, I need all of the information from both tables to pull into a query, and this is where I have problems. The two tables are pulling the same data, but they column titles might not necessarily be the same. For now, I'm assuming they are. How can I get it so that the data from both tables pull into the correct column together?

Here's an example of code (I can't post the real code for certain reasons):

```
SELECT system1_vehiclecolor, system1_vehicleweight, system1_licenseplate, system2_vehiclecolor, system2_vehicleweight, system2_licenseplate 
FROM system1, system2
```

To further explain this, I want the table to have a column for vehiclecolor, vehicleweight, and licenseplate that combines all of the information. Currently, the way I have it, it is making a column for each of the names in each table, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Tag your question correctly. Don't use the MySQL tag for MS-Access questions.

Comment: I am in Access but I'm editing the query through SQL so I thought it was the same thing

Comment: MySQL and Access both use SQL. That doesn't make them the same.

Comment: Use a `UNION` of the two queries.

Comment: Better use a `UNION ALL` to avoid `DISTINCT` processing

Comment: When I try this, I get an error that reads "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."

Comment: When I'm doing this, is there any way to define a new column that combines the two fields? UNION, UNION ALL, OUTER JOIN, and FULL OUTER JOIN aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 queries to get this done
Select col1as c1 ,col2 col as c2  into resulttable from table1

Insert into resulttable (c1,c2) select colX as c1, colY as c2 from table2

Hope this will help you